# Why does my PC have a higher peak memory than my macbook laptop?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm asking because I can't run the program I'm working on on my much better computer.

I run the same line and profile the memory. On my newer 64 bit PC (8 gigs of ram) I run this line

```
%memit 1000000000 % np.arange(1000000000)
```

and I get a peak memory: 4497.02 MiB. For my 2012 64 bit macbook (same amount of ram), I run the same line, it takes 3x as long, but I get a peak memory: 2489 MiB. (16.1s vs 42.1)

How could this be? My desktop has a i5 3.3 Ghz, 64 bit, 256 Gb SSD and 2TB HDD.

Comment: Is one of them a Windows box and one of them something else?

Comment: Actually, wait, the macbook has a lower peak memory consumption? Weird.

Comment: Okay, looking at this closer, this line should take at least 8 GB peak memory consumption even if `arange` uses a 4-byte dtype - 4 GB for the `arange` and another 4 for the `%` result. It must be swapping to disk. If you want to work with arrays that big, you should buy more RAM.

Comment: Is the Mac running 64-bit Python?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, both are running 64 bit python.

Answer (score 1):

OS X Mavericks introduced memory compression and probably some memory pages are swapped on the ssd/hdd. Moreover, the Python interpreter might allocate the memory in different ways on each OS.